# xcode 6 and background image for iphones

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I need to create a background image to used in portrait mode in all iphones.
Can I create only one image large enough for iphone 6+ (1242 x 2208)and use that for the rest of iphones as well (4s, 5, 6, and etc)?

with that said, if I create a such image, then can I just simply place that under 1x, 2X, and 3X in images.xcassets?
I did a test in xcode and image appears fine in simulator, but not sure if is a right way of doing it?

Thanks
Borna

Answer (score 0):

You need to create diff. images for 1x , 2x , 3x Devices . but if you want to create only one image large enough for iphone6+ than ... add that image in images.xcassets as 3x image ... install xcode plugin manager from here http://alcatraz.io/  ... restart your Xcode ... press command+Shift+9 ... which will open xcode plugin manager ... search plugin named RTImageAsssets install it(or you can read full description from github link which will be available there) ... restart your Xcode ... open image.xcassests and click on image you have added as 3x .. now click on file option from top bar of xcode option .. click on ImageAssets and generate missing Assets ... which will automatically generate missing 1x and 2x images for your Image Automatically .

Hope This Helps!